# Google Places API Web Service Autocomplete for School and University types

Tags: php, autocomplete, google-api, google-places-api

Ref:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table1
https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3

I have checked the implementation of the "Autocomplete" feature available in the Place API and found that only some of the "types" values are allowed in the request like geocode, address, establishment, (regions), (cities).

I would like to use school, university in "Autocomplete" feature but it is only allowed in "Place Search" feature.

I don't want to point to any particular location and then search the nearby places, but instead get all the schools and universities as the autocomplete result.

Is this possible using the Google APIs or do I need to use any other alternative?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can instanciate your Autocomplete so results are restricted within a country with the componentRestriction option. You can also restrict results to a certain type of places with the types option, but the only choices are 'geocode', 'establishment', '(regions)', '(cities)'. Schools and universities are of 'establishment' type.
https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types
you can go throught this link to find what you need